# Jtable ResultSet y DefaultTableModel arroja resultado al final de la tabla Java Mysql

Tags: java, mysql

Hola tengo el siguiente error, cuando decido buscar un nombre con el siguiente código en java:

```
        private void tfNombreKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                    
           if(evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){//AL DAR ENTER CON EL TECLADO APLIQUE LA ACCION DE BUSQUEDA
           tablaResultados.requestFocus();//FOCUS A LA TABLA DE ABAJO DONDE SE MOSTRARA EL RESULTADO
        try {
             DefaultTableModel modelo= (DefaultTableModel)tablaResultados.getModel();
             Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/database","root","PASSWORDXXX");
             Statement stmt=con.createStatement();//importar java.sql.Statement./. Ejecuto sentencias en mysql
             ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE Nombre LIKE '%"+tfNombre.getText()+"%'");
        if(rs.next()) { //se valida si hay resultados
        do {
            String[] fila={rs.getString(1),rs.getString(2),rs.getString(3),rs.getString(4),rs.getString(5),rs.getString(6),rs.getString(7),rs.getString(8)};
            modelo.addRow(fila);
        }
        while(rs.next()); {
             }}
      } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Consultas.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}                                   
}
```

y **me arroja el resultado al final de la table**. Quisiera saber a que corresponde ese error. *Desde ya muchas gracias.*

### [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**La solucion es gracias Oscar G que aporto la ayuda**

Estaba asi:

```
        try {
        DefaultTableModel modelo= (DefaultTableModel)tablaResultados.getModel();
```

Y asi debe quedar: Agregar al final del .getModel(): **modelo.setRowCount(0);**

```
        try {
        DefaultTableModel modelo= (DefaultTableModel)tablaResultados.getModel();
        modelo.setRowCount(0);
```

Resultado final:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que al hacer la búsqueda cada que presionas una tecla, y no se encuentra lo que pones en el campo nombre, se genera una fila vacía, entonces, debes de limpiar la tabla antes de agregar una fila nueva

```
DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();
modelo.setRowCount(0);
...
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias **Oscar G** perfecto eso era lo que me faltaba, estoy muy agradecido. Te pasaste!! Gracias @OscarG

Comment: De nada, para eso está la comunidad :)

Answer (score 0):

No me habia percatado bien de la pregunta, si es una consulta imagino que no necesitas los resultados previos, intenta cuando hagas la consulta crear una nueva instancia del model y asi la vacias y a lo mejor te quitas eso que en alguna parte del codigo previo debes haberle introducido los campos vacios.

Podrias evitar el if poniendo primero el while, al final siempre vas a validar con el while

```
DefaultTableModel modelo= new DefaultTableModel();

while(rs.next()){
            String[] fila={rs.getString(1),rs.getString(2),rs.getString(3),rs.getString(4),rs.getString(5),rs.getString(6),rs.getString(7),rs.getString(8)};
            modelo.addRow(fila);
        }
tablaResultados.setModel(modelo);
```

Intenta hacerlo asi

Comment: Hola Jose, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, probé con **while** y funciona igual me arroja el resultado al final de la tabla, lo que deseo es que comience de arriba al inicio de la tabla, a mostrar el resultado.